# Spark read wholetextfiles

Tags: pyspark

I am writing code as

**Option1**

```
spark.read.option("wholeTextFiles", True).text("gs://abc.txt")
```

There are 2 lines in this txt file and so it is returning 2 records.

But when I write code like

**Option 2:**

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("gs://abc.txt")
```

It gives me 1 record.

I want result as single record but in form of dataframe which I can get from Option 2. I know I get RDD from option 2 and I can convert it into dataframe/dataset.

Could anyone please explain why option 1 is not working as option 2 as according to what I read both should work in similar fashion.

Note: code is written in pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [spark official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-text.html#data-source-option), the option should be **`wholetext`**, not `wholeTextFiles`.

Comment: Thank you my friend. The only change is that in Python wholetext is passed as argument to text function instead of as option. For ex.

spark.read.text("path", wholetext=True)---> correct way
spark.read.option("wholetext", True).text("path")---> wrong way